# How to expose Python api for elasticsearch

Tags: python, rest, curl, elasticsearch

I have inserted large amount of data(1 million) in **EllasticSearch**. Now i want to create a REST API to fetch the data from **EllasticSearch**.

I want to use CURL commands
(eg: `curl -i http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/2`)
for being able to get the json fields `having _id=2`

I found the following blog `https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask`
that helped me on how to create REST API, but i am not able to understand how do i extend this for ElasticSearch.

Comment: This [elasticsearch api python](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/) was found as first hit via google.wrap the calls in your rest-service implementation - you use the API and return the results found. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

Answer (score 0):

The `elasticsearch` python API is very convenient to create any kind of operation (inserting or fetching). You can find the doc's here:

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Just one hint, in my experience the `python api` tended to be slower then creating direct curl requests from the command line. Anyhow, it is very convenient to work  with. A query is as easy as the following snippet.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
res = es.index(index="index-logstash")
```